# Basic Git Workflow: Why is code in branches I pull not already committed?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

#### Hi

I recently tried to pull down a master branch to merge in my dev branch and noticed that all the changes made to master since my last pull aren't committed. Just wanted to see if anyone could explain why this is the case and why changes aren't automatically committed from the master branch.

Comment: What does that even mean? Code __in__ branches cannot be __not__ commited. Branches point to __commits__, they don't contain any code themself.

Comment: So if I've pulled down my master branch (just ran git pull), and I see a bunch of uncommitted changes when I run git status, have I run into a problem?

If branches point to commits, I would expect see that my master branch is up to date with the most recent commit made to master. Instead I'm seeing every file show up as un-added after pulling when I run git status... Is this expected behavior?

Hopefully that helps clarify my question, I don't remember having to pull down and then instantly commit the last time I used github.

Comment: You had uncommitted changes before you did the pull, or your git pull updated your gitignore which made some files no longer ignored and thus now shows as untracked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `git pull`.<sup>1</sup>

The `git pull` command means:

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second Git command, usually `git merge` unless I specified `git rebase`.

As a Git beginner, it's a good idea for you to use the two separate commands.  Sure, it's a bit annoying to have to type an extra 11 (merge) or 12 (rebase) characters, but you can *see* what the various steps do now.

The `git fetch` command has your Git reach out to some other Git repository—at the saved URL, from wherever you did the earlier `git clone` to get the repository in the first place—and get, from them, any new commits they have that you don't.

The `git merge` and `git rebase` commands operate on *commits*.  If you have not yet made any commits out of any updates you want, they won't do good things: they'll do nothing, or something bad.<sup>2</sup>

If `git merge` says that you need to commit first, you'll see that you need to commit first.  If you use `git pull`, it *should* generate the same complaints, but—especially if you have told it to use rebase and autostash—it won't do that for some cases.

The extra "magic" that `git pull` appears to insert makes beginners think it does more than it really does, and then they get confused when it doesn't do what they want.  It never really did, but sometimes what it *did* do happened to be good enough and achieved the same effect.  In other words, using `git pull` encourages bad habits, which eventually come back to haunt you.  So don't use `git pull`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a rule for Git beginners.  For intermediate users, it's "now that you understand what it does, use it if you want", and for advanced users, it's "now that you understand what it does, don't use it because you know you don't want that."  More seriously, in the latest Git versions (2.30+) there are some configuration knobs for `git pull` that make it more useful in some situations, but you'll definitely need to know what to do about failure cases.

<sup>2</sup>In the bad old days of Git 1.5 or so, `git merge`, run with uncommitted work, could make a big mess where you could never quite get your original work back, after merge partially wrecked it with merge conflicts.  One learned not to run `git merge` without first running `git status` to check that everything was committed.

Modern Git is generally a lot better, but it's still a good habit to check first.